How to access GitHub deployment environment in the following steps
Within a job in GitHub we are able to define the environment, can we access it in the following steps? The closest I could get is presented in the snippet below. But it would have been great if this information was available in the github context.
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    #inputs:
    #  target-env:
    #    type: environment
    #    default: dev
  
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ vars.ENVIRONMENT_DEV }}
    
    steps:
      - name: GitHub Context
        run: echo "${GITHUB_CONTEXT}"
        env:
          GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}
      - name: Job Context
        run: echo "${JOB_CONTEXT}"
        env:
          JOB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(job) }}
      - name: Steps Context
        run: echo "${STEPS_CONTEXT}"
        env:
          STEPS_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(steps) }}
      - name: Runner Context
        run: echo "${RUNNER_CONTEXT}"
        env:
          RUNNER_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(runner) }}
      - name: Strategy Context
        run: echo "${STRATEGY_CONTEXT}"
        env:
          STRATEGY_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(strategy) }}
      - name: Matrix Context
        run: echo "${MATRIX_CONTEXT}"
        env:
          MATRIX_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(matrix) }}
      - name: Print Environment
        run: echo ${{ vars.ENVIRONMENT_DEV }}


I think you should directly reference environment variables or use the env keyword to set and access them.
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: 
      name: ${{ secrets.ENVIRONMENT_DEV }}

